# can I be able to host DotCMS project on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, content-management-system, dotcms

I am looking for an easy to use opensource CMS for creating java web applications , that can work on Google app engine.

Comment: You could always try it out, and see if you get a SecurityException for a restricted class. This is the reason most libraries won't work on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

As dotCMS expects to read and write to disk (to store files, css, images, etc) I am pretty sure that it will not work on App Engine without some heavy modification.  I do know that it WILL work on Google's Compute Engine.